# Active classnames in menu on a one-page website using GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm using a single page template with GatsbyJS on which the menu scrolls to the different sections of the same page (#home, #about, #portfolio, etc). Is there a way to set an active classname on the links, highlighting the link the user is on?

Comment: https://makotot.github.io/react-scrollspy/ - Using this quick easy plugin can help anyone looking for this info

Answer (score 3):

**Link** provides two options for adding styles to the active link:

`activeStyle` — a style object that will only be applied when the current item is active

`activeClassName` — a class name that will only be added to the Link when the current item is active

**Follow official docs**: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#add-custom-styles-for-the-currently-active-link

```js
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

const SiteNavigation = () => (
  <nav>
    <Link
      to="/"
      {/* This assumes the `active` class is defined in your CSS */}
      activeClassName="active"
    >
      Home
    </Link>
    <Link
      to="/about/"
      activeStyle={{ color: "red" }}
    >
      About
    </Link>
  </nav>
)
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with in-route hash links?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `activeStyle` or `activeClassName` prop to add styling attributes to the rendered element when it matches the current URL, and Gatsby also supports React Router's props `exact`, `strict`, `isActive`, and `location`. If any of these props are set, then React Router's `NavLink` component will be used instead of the default Link.

Example:

```
import Link from "gatsby-link"

render () {
 <div>
  <Link
   to="/another-page/"
   activeStyle={{
     color: 'red'
   }}
   innerRef={(el) => { this.myLink = el }}
  >
   Another page
  </Link>
 </div>
}
```

Visit https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-link

Comment: thomasna82, I think that this only works when navigating to a different page. Correct me if I'm wrong. I'm using the following navigation for the different sections on the same page:
`<ul className="menu first">
            <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT МЕ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            </ul>`

Comment: You are correct.  I misunderstood what you were asking.

Answer (score 1):

I did it the hard way as I couldn't find another solution:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Menu.css';

class Menu extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            home: true,
            about: false,
            portfolio: false
        }
        this.handleActive = this.handleActive.bind(this)
    }

    handleActive(button) {
        switch (button) {
            case 'home':
                this.setState({
                    home: true,
                    about: false,
                    portfolio: false
                });
                break;
            case 'about':
                this.setState({
                    home: false,
                    about: true,
                    portfolio: false
                });
                break;
            case 'portfolio':
                this.setState({
                    home: false,
                    about: false,
                    portfolio: true
                });
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="nav-wrap">
                <nav>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
                    <label htmlFor="checkbox1">
                        <ul className="menu first">
                            <li><a
                                className={this.state.home ? 'active' : null}
                                onClick={() => this.handleActive('home')}
                                href="#home">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a
                                className={this.state.about ? 'active' : null}
                                onClick={() => this.handleActive('about')}
                                href="#about">ABOUT МЕ
            </a></li>
                            <li><a
                                className={this.state.portfolio ? 'active' : null}
                                onClick={() => this.handleActive('portfolio')}
                                href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <span className="toggle">☰</span>
                    </label>
                </nav>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Menu;
```

Answer (score 1):

As brooksrelyt noted in the comment above, you can easily use `react-scrollspry` to add a unique class name to the hash link that has been clicked.  Here is how I use it:

```
import { Text } from 'rebass/styled-components'
import Scrollspy from 'react-scrollspy'

  <Scrollspy
    items={['home', 'features', 'faq']}
    currentClassName="isCurrent"
  >
    <Link to="#home">Home</Link>
    <Link to="#features">Features</Link>
    <Link to="#faq">FAQ</Link>
  </Scrollspy>

  <Text id="home">Home</Text>
  <Text id="features" mt={'400vh'}>Features</Text>
  <Text id="faq" mt={'150vh'}>FAQ</Text>
```

In short, you wrap your links with a `Scrollspy` component and include (at the very least) two mandatory props: `items` and `currentClassName`.

- `items` is an array of the hash names (without the hash character)
- `currentClassName` is the name of the class you want to add to the selected link.

NOTE:  I included the `rebass` Text component because it did not work properly for me when I used a simple div.  You should [read the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollspy#usage) for how to use it in your particular case - as there are other props that may be needed in different situations.

Answer (score 0):

I did a website some weeks ago with this feature. I created a function to know what section are the active and put it on the state in react. This function is called everytime the user move the scrollbar.

In render, I change de className of the elements depending the element of the state. In every section/element that i want to track I put an ID.

Util function:

```
/**
 * Helper function to get an element's exact position
 * @param  {element}  element
 * @return {x,y}
 */
export function getPosition(el) {
  var xPos = 0;
  var yPos = 0;

  while (el) {
    if (el.tagName == "BODY") {
      // deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and page scroll
      var xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      var yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop);
    } else {
      // for all other non-BODY elements
      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    }

    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPos,
    y: yPos
  };
}
```

On React component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    this.handleScroll();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

handleScroll() {
    const {inAnimation} = this.state;

    let activeElement = false;

    this.props.data.items.forEach((value,i) => {
        let element = document.getElementById(value.url.substring(1));
        if(getPosition(element).y <= 0){
            activeElement = value.url;
        }
    });
    this.setState({
        activeElement
    });
    }
}
render(){
     ...
     items.map((item, i) => {
        return <li key={i}>
            <a className={'menu-item' + (activeElement == item.url ? ' active': '')}>{item.title}</a>
        </li>;
    });
     ...
}
```